# Activity timeline - fields "From" and "To" are not populated when email is in "Next Steps" section

Tags: email, activity

when I create new EmailMessage object and assign to a sObject, then in activity timeline for this sObject, a new entry appear in "Next Steps" section, but "from" and "to" fields in timeline are empty. When I move this entry to the "Past Activities", then "from" and "to" field appear. When I move this entry back to the "Next Steps", then "from" and "to" fields disappears.
To move this entry I update Task.Status = "In Progress" or Task.Status = "Completed". What can I do to what to do so that they fields do not disappear in "Next Steps" section?[image: my activity timeline]